# Where can I see how many users my Twitter-Application?

Tags: oauth, twitter

I created a Twitter-Application and want to know how many user use it (gave access to it).
I also remember seeing such a value when I was developing it, but can't find it anymore.

Can I see it somewhere or is my mind playing games with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter used to display this number when you opened the application settings at http://twitter.com/oauth_clients, but it appears that they have taken this very useful number away.

Answer (score 0):

You can email Taylor from Twitter to get the number.

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/979d3d5bdfa06083/

You can get his email here:

http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=PMv52RwAAADziQ9bdKwaEHKLHT047zxKsEWQaXEousxizvRjwHNGlw